# Cannot Unwrap tabBar Frame

Tags: swift

I'm trying to extract a frame from a tabBar but I'm getting an error stating:

`Could not find member 'frame'.`

This works:

```
let frame : CGRect? = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame
```

Yet this doesn't:

```
let frame : CGRect = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around this by doing the following:

```
let optFrame : CGRect! = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame
let frame = optFrame as CGRect
```